# JSF and PrimeFaces custom component with other components inside

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, custom-component

**Description:**

I am creating an **e-shop** in JSF. On the right side I want to have the all categories of my shop.
I use recursive method to go through all categories (category can have parent category).

So the way I have choosen to do it is creating my own component.
*Is this thinking correct?*
How to do it this way or maybe I should try something else?

My attempt of solving this problem:

- Create **custom component** which `extends UIComponentBase` (maybe I should extends
  something else).
- Then create another components (**CommandButtons**) inside of this component ,
  which will be added to host the component.

Another issue is how can I launch `actionListener` of my button?
Beacause they are not automatically launched?
Has anybody created these kinds of components?

Answer (score 1):

You're basically looking for an UI component which can render a tree hierarchy. [PrimeFaces](http://primefaces.org) already offers two tree based components out the box, the [`<p:tree>`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/tree/basic.xhtml) and [`<p:treeTable>`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/treetable/basic.xhtml). Click the links to see several showcase examples.

If you intend to have full freedom over the markup of a tree hierarchy, then you may find the [OmniFaces](http://omnifaces.org) [`<o:tree>`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/components/tree) more useful. It does not render any HTML, so you have all HTML freedom to markup the tree nodes accordingly.

Or if you really insist in developing your own and thus reinventing the wheel, look in the source code of those components. They are open source.